# Finding number not in list with wildcards

Tags: algorithms, polynomial-time, lists

I have a list like this:

```
1*0*0
1**0*
0*0**
001**
```

Where the number of elements in each row is $n$ and * is a wildcard for 0 or 1. I need a polynomial-time algorithm that can determine if there exists an $n$-bit number that does not equal any of the rows. Does anyone know of an algorithm that could do this? I've been thinking about evaluating the total number of possible solutions for each row and subtracting from $2^n$ but I can't figure out how to delete duplicates in polynomial time.

Comment: Maybe use regular expressions?

Comment: I thought about that but you would have to regex over a list of all numbers from 0 to $2^n$ which would obviously require polynomial time to generate and work with.

Comment: Unless there's some other way to use regex that I didn't think of :)

Comment: Satisfiability.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to use a regex that you didn't think of.  hint: look up how to take the complement of a finite automata.

Comment: @WanderingLogic would that run in polynomial time on $n$?

Comment: No.  It is polynomial in $r n$ where $r$ is the number of rows and $n$ is the number of characters in each row.  I don't know how to solve the problem without looking at every character in every row at least once.

Comment: @WanderingLogic would it be $rn$ even with the wildcards? Because there are at least  $2^{n-3}$ elements in each row because of the wildcards.

Comment: No, I'm wrong.  The problem is that the complementing algorithm only works on DFA, so you need to convert the NFA to DFA, which can take exponential time.  Because of the structure of your problem the exponential explosion is only in $r$, but not in $n$.

Comment: René, I rolled back your edit because it seemed to turn the question into nonsense. Did you mean to do something else?

Comment: Sorry, that was just to test something, never mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reduce from SAT. Consider a CNF formula $\phi = C_1 \land C_2 \land \ldots \land C_m$ over a set of variables $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Construct an instance of your problem as follows:

For each clause $C_i$, create a row (i.e. binary string) $B_i = b_1 b_2 \ldots b_n$, where

$$ b_k = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\overline x_k \in C_i \\
0 & \text{if } x_k \in C_i \\
* & \text{if } x_k, \overline x_k \notin C_i
\end{cases}$$

We can preprocess $\phi$ to remove any clauses that contain both a literal and its negation, as these will of course always be satisfied and do not affect the result.

Any binary string $S$ that solves your problem also yields a satisfying assignment to $\phi$, using the reduction that sets  $x_i$ to the value of $S_i$.

Thus your problem is $NP$-hard. Since it is also clearly in $NP$, it is also $NP$-complete.